# Beautiful Soup Strip html caption tags, th class tags and retrieve data not in list

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I have created a web scraper that goes into cfbstats.com/2014/player/index.html and retrieves all the college football teams and the links of the football teams. From there it goes into each link and takes the roster and players link. Finally it goes into each players link and takes his stats.

I am currently having a problem with the taking the players stats. When I call the header of each table I get printed output [Tackle] and when call the first row of the table I get [G]. I would like to get rid of those tags. I have been able to not have them for my past functions. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import csv
import sys
import json
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlrd
import xlwt






def getCollegeandURL():



    f = open('colleges.csv', 'w')

    f.write("Teams" + "," + "," + "URL" + '\n')
    originalurl = "http://www.cfbstats.com/2014/player/index.html"
    base = requests.get("http://www.cfbstats.com/2014/player/index.html")
    base = base.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(base)





   # this is to find all the colleges in the div conference
   mydivs = soup.find_all('div',{'class': 'conference'}) 

   ##g is an excel document for the roster
   g = open('rosters.csv', 'w')
   g.write("College Rosters" + '\n' + '\n' + 'College' + ',' + 'Playernumber' + ',' + 'Player Last Name' + ',' +'Player First Name' + ',' + 'Position' + ',' + 'Year' + ',' + 'Height' + ',' + ' Weight' + ',' +'Hometown' + ',' + 'State' + ',' + 'Last School' + ',' + '\n')

   # h is an excel for each player stats
   h = xlwt.Workbook()

   # this for loop finds writes each college to a line
   for div in mydivs:
        urls= div.findAll('a')


    # this is to pull all the college names and each of their links
        for url in urls:


            college = url.text
            url = url.attrs['href']

            teamurl = originalurl[:23]+url

            f.write(college[:]+ ',' + ',' + teamurl[:]+'\n')


            scrapeRosters(college, teamurl, g, h)







############################################################################ 
def scrapeRosters(college, teamurl, g, h):

    # create the excel documents
    # this gets the pages of teams
    roster = requests.get(teamurl)
    roster = roster.text
    roster = BeautifulSoup(roster)






    teamname = roster.find_all('h1' , {'id': 'pageTitle'})

    teamAndPlayers = {}
    table = roster.find_all('table', {'class' : 'team-roster'})



    for i in table:

        rows = i.find_all('tr')



        for row in rows[1:]:

            data = [str(i.getText()) for i in row('td')]
            link = row('td')[1]('a')





            if len(link) > 0:
                link = str(link[0]['href'])
                data = [str(link)] + data

                # unpacking data into variables

                (playerurl, playernumber, playerName,    playerPosition,YearinCollege, playerHeight, playerWeight, playerHometown, lastSchool) = data

                # creating the full player url
                playerurl = teamurl[:23] + playerurl

                # repacking the data

                data = (college, playernumber, playerName, playerPosition,YearinCollege, playerHeight, playerWeight, playerHometown, lastSchool)





                g.write(college + ',' + playernumber + ',' + playerName + ',' + playerPosition + ','+ YearinCollege + ',' + playerHeight + ',' + playerWeight + ',' + playerHometown + ',' + lastSchool+ ',' + ',' + playerurl + ',' + '\n')



                playerStats(data, playerurl, h)       


############################################################################
def playerStats(data,playerurl, h):

    playerurl = requests.get(playerurl)
    playerurl = playerurl.text
    playerurl = BeautifulSoup(playerurl)



    tablestats = playerurl.find_all('table', {'class' : 'player-home'})


    (college, playernumber, playerName, playerPosition,YearinCollege, playerHeight, playerWeight, playerHometown, lastSchool) = data

    #print college, playernumber, playerName

    print college, playerName, playernumber

    for x in tablestats:

        caption = x.find_all('caption')







        rows = x.find_all('tr')

##        caption = caption.strip

        for row in rows:
            headers = x.find_all('th')

            headers = [str(i.getText()) for i in row('tr')]

            stats = [str(x.getText()) for x in row('td')]

            print caption, headers, stats


############################################################################
def main():
    getCollegeandURL()



main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't work so hard, your data is [already available in parseable form](https://github.com/10-01/NCAA-Football-Analytics/tree/master/data).

Comment: Again, why? The API is designed so the webage can be changed and still keep your code from breaking.